# Why do we need "this" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have [read this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) about "this" in TypeScript/Javascript. And wonder why typescript needs "this" in front of members and functions?

If I am in a callback I would use a fat arrow so typescript should know how to prefix member methods with "self" instead of "this"

But I guess that. there is a good explanation.

Comment: It would clarify the question a lot if you could show a code example of what you mean.

Comment: The 'fat arrow' is a lambda expression, which is actually an anonymous function. Using `this` in the anonymous function points to the function itself. that's why you should define 'this' to another variable (eg `let self = this;`) prior using it in the lambda. You should check up on variable scopes in javascript because typescript transpiles to javascript.

Comment: Related: https://www.codementor.io/javascript/tutorial/understanding--this--in-javascript

Comment: @NicoVanBelle: That's incorrect - fat arrow functions in JavaScript/TypeScript bind `this` to the scope in which they are defined, not the function itself. Avoiding stuff like `let self = this;` is part of the reason why arrow functions exist to begin with.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle: In other words: `() => { return this; }` is the same as `let self = this; function() { return self; }`. See [this part of the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) for the specifics.

Comment: @JoeClay you are 100% correct. I've never even noticed this was actually possible now. Thank you.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle: No problem, hopefully it'll save you some typing in the future :)

Comment: I just wonder if it would be possible to make a typescript transpiler where where "this" is optional.

Comment: Again, an example would clarify the question, but if I understand you correctly: if you have e.g. `this.example()` and leave out `this`, how does the compiler know that you mean to refer to an object's member method `example` and not a variable or token called `example` that's in the same scope?

Comment: @MartinAndersen _"I just wonder if it would be possible to make a typescript transpiler where where "this" is optional."_ And the answer is: **No**. TypeScript is designed as a superset of JavaScript. The code `myFunction()` differs from `something.myFunction()`. I posted a link that explains how works `this` in JavaScript. You should read it.